# Count distinct while grouping in MS Access 2010

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a database of sales and I want to be able to see what has sold during a particular time frame over the years i.e. see what sold most in the last 10 years between July 1 and July 15. Problem is that not all the items were sold every year, and I need to be able to get the average sold. I was able to count distinct years in MySQL but after migrating to Access I can't figure out how to count distinct while still grouping by the individual product.

Relevant fields are StockID (the items' unique id) and TransDate (a datetime that I pull the year from) I've tried things similar to `SELECT Count(*) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT YEAR(Transdate) from Sales)` inside my other query but that always gives me the count from all items (basically giving the number of years in the database) rather than a count for each item.

TL;DR I can either count distinct on the whole DB which is useless or group by StockID without counting distinct which is mildly less useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you are looking for  select with group by ..

```
 select  StockID, count(*) 
 from   (select distinct stockID, Year( Transdate) from  my_table )
 group  StockID
```

Comment: Close, but I want to have only one line per StockID with a count of the years that item was sold. This gives me a line for each year for each StockID.

Comment: Great, that works perfectly. Now I just have to figure out how to add it to my other query! Thanks!